# PHP remember chat open/close method

Tags: php, jquery, session, cookies

On my site in the bottom left hand corner there's a chat tab that you can open and close with a click. The button is named 'trigger' and the chat panel is named 'panel'. I'm not familiar with javascript really, I just cobbled this together from existing scripts, anyway, the code I use that works this is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".trigger").click(function(){
    $(".panel").toggle("fast");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

What happens though is if the user opens chat then goes to another page, the chat must be reopened again. I need a way to keep the chat open if it's already open.

Maybe something in the body onload tag? And using sessions?

Note: My site's in php

Comment: set a cookie using javascript, check if that cookie exists on document ready and if it does then run .click();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) you can save state of the chat class toggle. Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

  if($.cookie('panel-active')) {
      $(".trigger").toggleClass("active",true);
  }

  $(".trigger").click(function(){
    $(".panel").toggle("fast");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $.cookie('panel-active', $(this).hasClass("active"), { path: '/' });
    return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```